# Python list: add string before and after item

Tags: python

Got a list as a variable.
The items are transferred to an HTML formatted email.
If a list item starts with '-', it needs to get HTML code before and after it to get the text in red.

So basically: if a list item starts with '-', I need to add a string before, and one after it.
I got this already:

```
mylist = ['no problem','also no problem','-this got to be red','no problem here']
before = '<p style="color:red">'
after = '</p>'

for i in mylist:
    if i.startswith('-'):
        i = newstr = " ".join((before,i,after))
        mylist.append(i)

print(mylist)
```

The problem: it adds the new variable, but also keeps the old one.
I need to replace it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't modify a list when you are iterating over it. Also, don't reassign `i`. Just use `newstr`.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use list comprehension here.  Replace the for loop with this:

```
mylist = [' '.join((before, s, after)) if s.startswith('-') else s
               for s in mylist]
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension would suit this situation perfectly. Also why not use `str.format` instead of `str.join`:

```
mylist = ['no problem','also no problem','-this got to be red','no problem here']
make_red = '<p style="color:red"> {} </p>'.format

mylist = [make_red(s) if s.startswith('-') else s for s in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the assignment operator `=` instead of `append`, and enumerate the list so you can operate on it using indexes:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(mylist):
    if mylist[i].startswith('-'):
        mylist[i] = ' '.join(before, mylist[i], after)
```

Answer (score 0):

`mylist.append(i)` will add new item to your list, you can update your list by using their index

```
for i, item in enumerate(mylist):
    if item.startswith('-'):
        mylist[i] = " ".join((before,item,after))
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
before = '<p style="color:red">'
after = '</p>'

# Option 1
mylist = ['no problem','also no problem','-this got to be red','no problem here']
for i, s in enumerate(mylist):
    if s.startswith('-'):
        mylist[i] = " ".join((before,s,after))
print(mylist)

# Option 2
mylist = ['no problem','also no problem','-this got to be red','no problem here']
mylist = list(map(lambda s: " ".join((before,s,after)) if s.startswith('-') else s, mylist))
print(mylist)

# Option 3
mylist = ['no problem','also no problem','-this got to be red','no problem here']
mylist = [" ".join((before,s,after)) if s.startswith('-') else s for s in mylist]
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are appending. You need to replace it.
Small change to your code here :

```
mylist = ['no problem','also no problem','-this got to be red','no problem here']
before = '<p style="color:red">'
after = '</p>'

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if mylist[i].startswith('-'):
        mylist[i] =  " ".join((before,mylist[i],after))

print(mylist)
```